# How to perform Controller.destroy action asynchronously in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I can easily delete the entries of `post` `synchronously` in rails application by following code:

## views

```
<% @post.each do |post| %>
 <tr>
   <td colspan="3"><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

## Controller class

```
def destroy
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 @post.destroy
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html redirect_to(posts_url) }
   format.xml  { head :ok }
 end
end
```

This works fine. How make this `destroy` process `async`. So, that I will not required to add `route` or `refresh the page`.

## Edit

Adding more explanation

Task is to make `destroy` method `async`. So that the client will not wait for the response and `destroy` method will run in background `async`. Also the destroy method has no guaranteed completion time.

Another example could be: I have to delete multiple post at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making `Async` request you need `Ajax` and basic `javascript` to remove the code of `<td>`.

First change your `views` code to :

```
<% @post.each do |post| %>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3"><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, :method=> :delete, id: post.id, :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger', data: { confirm: 'Are you Sure?', remote: true } %> </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Above code says that it will call the `destroy` method of `PostController` class. Now you need to make some changes in `destroy` method of `controller` class

```
def destroy
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 @post.destroy
 respond_to do |format|
   format.js 
   format.html { redirect_to(posts_url) }
 end
end
```

Above code is pretty understandable, except why we use `respond_to`. In rails we can render the data in two ways:

1. Javascript
2. HTML

we will use `javascript` to render the code because it's a easy way to remove the `<td>` tag with the help of `ID`.

Now we need a `js` file to render the response of `destroy` method. To do this add `destroy.js.erb` in the same folder of your `views`.

Add this following code in `destroy.js.erb`:

```
 var element = document.getElementById("<%= @post.id %>");
 element.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
```

You are done!
I will recommend you to read : http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/the-detailed-guide-on-how-ajax-works-with-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 2):

Try `remote: true` option,

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', post, :method => :delete, remote: true, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %>

def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.destroy

  # Just Guessing you have @posts to refresh and `posts_template` using it.
  @posts = Post.all 

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html redirect_to(posts_url) }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
    format.js { render 'posts.js.erb' }
  end
end
```

## posts.js.erb

```
$('some_element').replaceWith('<%=j render 'posts_template' %>');
```

Please change as you need. I am just guessing.

Comment: Don't I need to make any changes in `controller class` because it is redirecting to a page after submitting the request?

Comment: yes, add `format.js {}` block as same as `xml` or `html` in respond_to block. Add your changes in that.

Comment: I am little bit confused because we are not passing any parameters to `format.js {}. Please have a look at http://pastebin.com/tuiXce8f

Also I tried and it's working.  But after deleting the element page is not refreshing. This is the proper way to run `Asynchronous` for `destroy` method  or it just a tweak ?

Comment: you have to add a code in `format.js {}` block that, what you need to change after request is completed.  Like you can render any js partial, any javascript, etc ...

Comment: I did that. Is it the proper way to do it? because clinet is  still waiting for the response

Comment: Yes it is the way. ` because clinet is still waiting for the response` ? what exactly happens in that.  Or you may add more context in your question. That will help Us.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please have a look at edit-1 section

Comment: @SnowClue Aswer is updated, please try with your changes.