# Ajax record delete not appended to HTML

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I am venturing into AJAX and would like to delete a record of a model and followed this thread : [How to perform Controller.destroy action asynchronously in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129766/how-to-perform-controller-destroy-action-asynchronously-in-rails)

**models:**

```
Photographe
Photographephoto
```

**views/photographes/edit.html.erb**

```
<div id="sectionimages" class="gutter-0 row" >
          <% @photographe.photographephotos.all.each do |f| %>
              <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col">
                <%= link_to professionnel_photographe_photographephoto_path(@photographe.professionnel.id,@photographe.id, f.id), method: :delete, remote: 'true', id: "destruction"+f.id.to_s do %>
                    <div class="killimage"  >
                      <%= image_tag f.image.url(:small) %>
                      <%= image_tag 'fatcrosswhite.svg', class: 'imgover' %>
                    </div>
                <% end %>
              </div>
          <% end %>
 </div>
```

link to `Photographephotos#destroy` is `remote` and there's an `id` like "destruction134"

**photographephotos_controller.rb**

```
def destroy

      @imagedestroyed = Photographephoto.find(params[:id])
      @imagedestroyedid = @imagedestroyed.id
      @imagedestroyed.image = nil
      @imagedestroyed.save
      @imagedestroyed.destroy

      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end

end
```

**views/photographephotos/destroy.js.erb**

```
var destroyelement = document.getElementById("<%= "destruction"+@imagedestroyedid.to_s %>");
destroyelement.parentNode.remove();
```

Problem is the file is indeed deleted but I have to refresh the page to see it removed. It seems the javascript is not effective. (I am trying to remove the parent of the link which is a Bootstrap DIV)

Comment: What do you see with `console.log(destroyelement);`?

Comment: `destroyelement is undefinded` (I typed it in Explorer console but I am not very familiar with it)

Comment: But I guess the JS is triggered only when the remote call to Destroy action is called. Maybe if the JS is mispelled, it's not appended to my page. I don't know much of JS and maybe the `parentNode.remove();` bit is not correct according to my DOM structur then skipping the JS ...

Comment: Try with `destroyelement.parentElement.remove();`.

Comment: thanks. It worked. But I had also a `redirect_to` at the bottom of my Destroy controller as this controller had no html nor js template originally. I thought the `format` would override that but it seems it kind of messed things up..